# How to run Selenium scripts in multiple browsers from Jenkins

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have to run selenium scripts in multiple browsers like Chrome, IE, FF, etc. How can I parameterize these browsers from Jenkins.

Answer (score 3):

You need [selenium-grid](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) in order to run on several browsers. It might be cumbersome to setup selenium grid on various OS and OS versions depending on the requirement and it requires some effort to keep up and maintain that infrastructure as well.

Instead I would suggest to use providers like www.saucelabs.com who provide almost all widely used OS + versions + browsers as a service and based on your language of choice to write the tests, there are APIs to get the job done.

If you are curious to learn and maintain a selenium grid on your own, here is a quick [sample](https://github.com/sahas-/SeleniumGrid-GCE-Kubernetes) using docker containers.

Answer (score 1):

We use selenium with Jenkins in our company and what we do is to use docker containers.

Launch the browser with this command

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox
```

Then run your script using a remote web driver for each browser.

Regards

Comment: we don't have IE images for the docker containers just yet.  maybe in the future.  your solution here will work for chrome and firefox, but not ie, as the user specified

Comment: Now that Windows Containers is out the idea to have a docker container with IE or Edge becomes a tangible posibility

Comment: absolutely.  i've been researching into it.  i believe that they can only be built/run on windows machines however?  :(