# How to run headless selenium scripts, Host and Browser independent

Tags: java, docker, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration

I want to run a given headless selenium "script" built in Java on a CI job, independent of host (and browser).

I can build a jar and run the "script" on a terminal, I just have to be careful enough to point-to and configure the right driver depending on the OS and the browser of the host I run the script on. But, on CI hosts I don't necessarily control host and browser, if they're available at all.

So I want to make the script's execution independent of the host and browser where the script runs. It could be running on a slave instance of Jenkins, Travis, Gitlab CI, etc.

There are a couple of questions made previously that are very directed towards a given host and browser combination. I could take the host out of the question and have the browser available, for example, via a container.

If the browser was available as a container image, I could run the script against different browsers, each with it's own image. And I'd have the proper drivers already prepared for those browser instances.

Would that be viable and what's the simplest way I can do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is viable.
As shown on "[How to run Selenium scripts in multiple browsers from Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39969402/7468990)
" one can raise a docker image with a browser and then use a [Remote WebDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.java) to connect to that browser.

[Selenium grid](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2), also referenced on an answer to that question is a viable option to raise at the same time multiple nodes of any given browser, useful for concurrent scenarios, which is not the particular case for this question.